# Keycloak: Temporary and permanent lockout of user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to "implement" the following flow in keycloak as idp:

1. The user has 3 failure logins
2. The user should be temporary locked for 5 minutes
3. The user has 3 failure logins again
4. The user should be temporary locked for 5 minutes again
5. The user has 3 failure logins again
6. The user should be locked permanent
7. The user should receive an e-mail that he's locked permanent.

I saw the Brute Force detection under Authentication in Keycloak. But my scenario adress both the temporary and permanent lockout.

Do you have any idea about a possible approach to address this requirement?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Maybe implement your own BruteForceProtector as described below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloack has only one implementation of [BruteForceProtector](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/managers) in the box: [DefaultBruteForceProtector](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/managers/DefaultBruteForceProtector.java)

You can [implement your own provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#implementing-a-spi):

> Keycloak is designed to cover most use-cases without requiring custom code, but we also want it to be customizable. To achieve this Keycloak has a number of Service Provider Interfaces (SPI) for which you can implement your own providers.